# How to parse unicode data from xml

Tags: android, xml, unicode

I am using HttpPost to make webservice connection. I am able to retrieve the data except the unicode data. Those data if i want to display it looks different. I am working on Hebrew language.

```
private static String callRestWebService(
            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs, int action, String url) {
        String result = null;
        int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; // = 10 seconds
        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            result = httpclient.execute(request, handler);
            parse(result, action);
            result = null;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All XML data is Unicode, so I guess by Unicode you mean "characters outside the ASCII repertoire". You make two conflicting statements: you imply that you are unable to "retrieve" (or "parse") the input, and you also say that it "looks different" on output. You need to be much more precise. If your parse() method fails, tell us how it fails. If the data "looks different" on output, tell us how you displayed it and what it looks like.

Somewhere in your processing chain there is an encoding misunderstanding, where some component of your system is getting data in one encoding that it thinks is in another. Resolving such issues is difficult, and it can only be done with very precise information about the way data is flowing through the system and how all the components are configured.